# Is there an easy way to setup "example.com" MX records?

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, mx-record, hosts-file

I'm used to use /etc/hosts to fake "example.com" or other domains to point to my local web servers to make tests.

I'm trying to do some filtering tests on a multi-domain postfix and I need to fake several domain names to check how it responds without touching the real thing.

Is possible to do so, in a easy way, to make configuration test with a local mail server?

If it is not as easy tell me how to do it also :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up a local DNS server that hosts a few sample domains (nonexistant in reality), complete with MX records and all. Then create a group of test mail servers with addresses as listed in the test domains.

If you know DNS etc., it's really easy.

Comment: Yeah, that will be the standard way to do so. I only was wondering if there's an easy way that doesn't involve a DNS server a'la /etc/hosts file